# Is it possible to remove the form assistant in the mobile safari virtual keyboard?

Tags: ios, mobile, mobile-safari

For single form UI's the form assistant in the mobile safari virtual keyboard doesn't provide much value and reduces the useable space in the viewport. Is it possible to remove this section of the keyboard for forms that do not benefit from this?

Comment: Worse, when the iOS picker comes up for dropdowns, it doesn't seem to fire the right events for the underlying dropdown such as change.  So if you are creating cascading dropdowns for tree-ing in on information like car make/models, the "form assistant picker" doesn't populate correctly...  So it would be great to be able to prevent the form assistant from appearing.  Though the picker may be the only way to select from a dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

In essence, you must wait till the keyboard responds and then forcibly grab and remove that top bar. It's not pretty and definitely not perfect but it is a starting place. I'll post the refinement of this process as I work on it myself.

Here is the question. I implemented this using Trigger.IO and native plugins but, naturally, you can ignore that and just run it on your UIWebView: [How can I hide Form Assistant with iOS native plugins using Trigger.IO?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12945848/how-can-i-hide-form-assistant-with-ios-native-plugins-using-trigger-io/12970241#12970241)