# Remove form assistant from keyboard in iPhone standalone web app

Tags: iphone, html, css, iphone-web-app, iphone-standalone-web-app

Is it possible to remove the form assistant from the iPhone popup keyboard in a standalone web app? I know the general consensus is that it's not possible in Mobile Safari, but a standalone app runs in a `UIWebView`, and functions differently in several ways ([example](http://www.mobilexweb.com/blog/apple-phonegap-html5-nitro)), so I'm hoping this might be possible.

You can see it here right above the keyboard:

[image]

The Previous and Next buttons cycle between `<form>` inputs. But I have a single `<input>` element, so they are disabled. The Done button hides the keyboard, but since I have a height-flexible `<ul>` (that takes up the space between the keyboard and the `<input>`), and I have nothing else on this page, it serves no purpose.

On a tiny screen, and with almost half the screen taken up by the keyboard, the 44 pixels that make up this toolbar are a huge waste of space (an entire `<li>`'s worth).

Native iOS apps *can* remove it, so I know it's at least possible on the phone, I've just not discovered a way to do it in a web app. This is from the Facebook app and the page is very similar to mine:

[image]

I've tried using an `<input>` not wrapped in a `<form>` and also using a `contenteditable` `<div>`, but the results were the same. There are several custom `-webkit-` styles to control various aspects of the web app interface, but they are poorly documented, and a search turned up nothing on this.

Any way to remove the form assistant in a web app?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All signs point to this [not being possible](http://groups.google.com/group/rhomobile/browse_thread/thread/bafefd764b7094fd/4425d2e36e329d4d?show_docid=4425d2e36e329d4d), including [several](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6485997/848090) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7472465/848090) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8459282/848090).

Comment: Those are all related to mobile Safari not in standalone mode. This is for a chrome-less web app. I'm hoping there is more control, but perhaps not.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't believe you get control over that with a chromeless app. Maybe someone will prove me wrong, though.

Comment: Any updated solutions for iOS 9.3.2? or is it still impossible?

Answer (score 12):

If you app is a web app wrapped in a native Objective-C app this is possible by manipulating Keyboard views.

first, register to receive the keyboardDidShow notification:

```objectivec
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardDidShow:) name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];
```

this will call the following method when keyboard shows up:

```objectivec
-(void)keyboardDidShow:(NSNotification*)notif
{
    NSArray *array = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows];
    
    for (UIWindow* wind in array) {
        for (UIView* currView in wind.subviews) {
            if ([[currView description] hasPrefix:@"<UIPeripheralHostView"]) {
                for (UIView* perView in currView.subviews) {
                    if ([[perView description] hasPrefix:@"<UIWebFormAccessory"]) {
                        [perView setHidden:YES];
                    }
                }
            
            }
        }
    }
}
```

this method goes over the views on screen looking for the form assistant and hiding it.

NOTE: Apple probably won't reject this, as i've seen it being used by Facebook etc, but this technique might break in upcoming iOS releases.

Comment: I am wrapping my app in a UIWebView for the final product, but have done everything "pre-wrap", so far. It looks like this may be the only solution to this problem though.

Comment: Use `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` instead of `UIKeyboardDidShowNotification` then you don't see the bar appear and then disappear again...

Comment: You should also do this `[perView removeFromSuperview];` otherwise the hidden view will swallow any touches and not pass them to the underlying `UIWebView`

Comment: @Besi that's wrong. UIKeyboardWillShowNotification is not working since the views are not instantiated before the keyboard appears.

Comment: @Besi it doesn't work for me either. By the way, I found a better version of the solution that @HeziCohen proposed. It can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13143689/how-to-find-uiwebview-toolbar-to-replace-them-on-ios-6#13146681). That solution uses `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` instead of `UIKeyboardDidShowNotification` (and it works) and, furthermore, gets rid of the gray horizontal line that remains after the form assistant bar is removed.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a category of UIView and "override" the behaviour of addSubview: like the example below. Call the method "exachangeMethods" from your applicationDidFinishLaunching of your AppDelegate.

```objectivec
#import "UIView+util.h"
#import <objc/runtime.h>

@implementation UIView (util)

// Swaps our custom implementation with the default one
// +load is called when a class is loaded into the system
+ (void) exchangeMethods
{
    SEL origSel = @selector(addSubview:);
    
    SEL newSel = @selector(customAddSubview:);
    
    Class viewClass = [UIView class];
    
    Method origMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(viewClass, origSel);
    Method newMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(viewClass, newSel);
    method_exchangeImplementations(origMethod, newMethod);
}
- (void) customAddSubview:(UIView *)view{
    
    if( [[view description]rangeOfString:@"<UIWebFormAccessory"].location!=NSNotFound) {
        return;
    }
    
    // This line at runtime does not go into an infinite loop
    // because it will call the real method instead of ours.
    return [self customAddSubview:view];
    
}

@end
```

Comment: Looks good, but I'm trying to do this in a web app, not native.

Comment: Very interesting solution to try swizzling for this... I will give it a shot.