# Remove Keyboard Form toolbar on ios7 leaves a blur behind

Tags: objective-c, cordova, ios7

I can remove the toolbar but I am left width a blur of the height the toolbar was.

Any idea on how to remove this?

The code below is the function. It's pretty straight forward.
I use this in a webview using phonegap.

```
-(void) removeBar {
    // Locate non-UIWindow.
    UIWindow * keyboardWindow = nil;
    for (UIWindow * testWindow in [
        [UIApplication sharedApplication] windows]) {
        if (![
            [testWindow class] isEqual: [UIWindow class]
        ]) {
            keyboardWindow = testWindow;
            break;
        }
    }

    // Locate UIWebFormView.
    for (UIView * possibleFormView in [keyboardWindow subviews]) {
        // iOS 5 sticks the UIWebFormView inside a UIPeripheralHostView.
        if ([
            [possibleFormView description] rangeOfString: @"UIPeripheralHostView"].location != NSNotFound) {

            // remove the border above the toolbar in iOS 6
            [
                [possibleFormView layer] setMasksToBounds: YES];

            for (UIView * subviewWhichIsPossibleFormView in [possibleFormView subviews]) {
                if ([
                    [subviewWhichIsPossibleFormView description] rangeOfString: @"UIWebFormAccessory"].location != NSNotFound) {
                    [subviewWhichIsPossibleFormView removeFromSuperview];

                    // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10746998/phonegap-completely-removing-the-black-bar-from-the-iphone-keyboard/10796550#10796550
                    UIScrollView * webScroll;
                    if ([
                        [
                            [UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 5.0) {
                        webScroll = [
                            [self webView] scrollView];
                    } else {
                        webScroll = [
                            [
                                [self webView] subviews] lastObject];
                    }

                    CGRect newFrame = [webScroll frame];

                    float accessoryHeight = [subviewWhichIsPossibleFormView frame].size.height;
                    newFrame.size.height += accessoryHeight;

                    [subviewWhichIsPossibleFormView removeFromSuperview];
                    [webScroll setFrame: newFrame];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: problem]
[image: problem]

**If you hit this problem**, make sure to head over to https://bugreport.apple.com and duplicate rdar://9844216

Comment: I have added the screenie :-)

Comment: Have you tested your app on iPhone 5s with this code? Is it working fine?

Comment: I found the solution for iOS 8. You can check it here: [ iOS 8 - Remove Previous/Next/Done UIKeyboard Toolbar inside a UIWebView][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25022089/remove-next-previous-buttons-inputaccessoryview-for-custom-keyboard-in-ios8

Comment: I found the solution for iOS 8. You can check it here: iOS 8 - Remove Previous/Next/Done UIKeyboard Toolbar inside a UIWebView

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25022089/remove-next-previous-buttons-inputaccessoryview-for-custom-keyboard-in-ios8

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
- (void)removeKeyboardTopBar {
// Locate non-UIWindow.
UIWindow *keyboardWindow = nil;
for (UIWindow *testWindow in [[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows]) {
    if (![[testWindow class] isEqual:[UIWindow class]]) {
        keyboardWindow = testWindow;
        break;
    }
}
// Locate UIWebFormView.
for (UIView *possibleFormView in [keyboardWindow subviews]) {
    if ([[possibleFormView description] hasPrefix:@"<UIPeripheralHostView"]) {
        for (UIView* peripheralView in possibleFormView.subviews) {

            // HERE!! hides the backdrop (iOS 7)
            if ([[peripheralView description] hasPrefix:@"<UIKBInputBackdropView"]) {
                [[peripheralView layer] setOpacity:0.0];
            }
            // hides the accessory bar
            if ([[peripheralView description] hasPrefix:@"<UIWebFormAccessory"]) {
                // remove the extra scroll space for the form accessory bar
                CGRect newFrame = diaryEditorView.scrollView.frame;
                newFrame.size.height += peripheralView.frame.size.height;
                diaryEditorView.scrollView.frame = newFrame;

                // remove the form accessory bar
                [peripheralView removeFromSuperview];
            }
            // hides the thin grey line used to adorn the bar (iOS 6)
            if ([[peripheralView description] hasPrefix:@"<UIImageView"]) {
                [[peripheralView layer] setOpacity:0.0];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: good answer. It can be improved though. There are two backdrop views: one under the form toolbar, the other under the keyboard itself. Your solution hides both backdrop views. As a result, the keyboard becomes transparent -- an undesirable side effect. I would modify your solution a bit: hide only the backdrop under the toolbar (its `y` coordinate is 0). For example, `CGRect rect = peripheralView.frame; if (rect.origin.y == 0) [[peripheralView layer] setOpacity:0.0];`

Comment: I still have a white or black background depending on the color of the webview. I think the webview does not get resized to the correct size.

Comment: This will work on any phonegap version only if the viewport meta height=device-height is set

Comment: Alexander's origin.y check worked well for me. This appears to be especially important on iOS 7.1.

Comment: ios noob here. does anyone know how to fix the "Use of undeclared identifier 'diaryEditorView'" error? thanks

Comment: @user2038156: This code is not working in iPhone 5s with iOS8. Do you have any suggestion that the code is also working in iPhone 5s?

Answer (score 1):

User2038156's answer did not worked well for me on 7.1 because it also excludes the panel behind the keyboard, making it completely transparent. To remove only the background of the extra area you can use this code:

```
- (void)removeBar {
    if(self.isHidingDoneBar){
        UIWindow *keyboardWindow = nil;
        for (UIWindow *testWindow in [[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows]) {
            if (![[testWindow class] isEqual:[UIWindow class]]) {
                keyboardWindow = testWindow;
                break;
            }
        }
        // Locate UIWebFormView.
        for (UIView *possibleFormView in [keyboardWindow subviews]) {
            if ([[possibleFormView description] hasPrefix:@"<UIPeripheralHostView"]) {
                for (UIView* peripheralView in possibleFormView.subviews) {

                    // HERE!! hides the backdrop (iOS 7)
                    if ([[peripheralView description] hasPrefix:@"<UIKBInputBackdropView"] && peripheralView.frame.size.height == 44) {
                        [[peripheralView layer] setOpacity:0.0];
                    }
                    // hides the accessory bar
                    if ([[peripheralView description] hasPrefix:@"<UIWebFormAccessory"]) {
                        // remove the extra scroll space for the form accessory bar
                        CGRect newFrame = webView.scrollView.frame;
                        newFrame.size.height += peripheralView.frame.size.height;
                        webView.scrollView.frame = newFrame;

                        // remove the form accessory bar
                        [peripheralView removeFromSuperview];
                    }
                    // hides the thin grey line used to adorn the bar (iOS 6)
                    if ([[peripheralView description] hasPrefix:@"<UIImageView"]) {
                        [[peripheralView layer] setOpacity:0.0];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I had the same issue. This fixed it! Thanks!                             if ([[peripheralView description] hasPrefix:@"<UIKBInputBackdropView"] && peripheralView.frame.size.height == 44) {
                        [[peripheralView layer] setOpacity:0.0];
                    }

Comment: I am working on Phonegap app. can you please tell me where I should add this code?

Comment: Works fine on iOS7, but I need this for iOS8... any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good quick way to accomplish the same in swift with only one line of code, done inside your custom UIResponder :

```
public override func becomeFirstResponder() -> Bool {

     if !self.isEditing {

            super.becomeFirstResponder()
            //TODO: Do some sanity checks here , this is a hack to remove the backdrop on iOS 7.0 +
            self.inputView?.superview?.subviews.first?.removeFromSuperview()

     }
}
```