# How to programmatically disable predictive view in WebView of iOS 8

Tags: uiwebview, ios8, ios-app-extension, uiinputviewcontroller

I'm designing a custom keyboard for iOS 8. It works fine on any UITextField but when it's in UIWebView, it shows predictions. Since it's allowed to have custom keyboard in iOS 8 I assume there should be a way to disable this view. Any help would be appreciated. Red area of the following picture:
[image]

Comment: I have an opposite problem - I also develop the custom keyboard and I don't know how to get the Prediction iOS view. How did u did it?

Comment: @tatiana_c It's basically a new question but I will answer you here. Yo cannot get the default prediction view by designing your own custom keyboard. If you want a prediction view you should design it from scratch by yourself. The reason that I have prediction view is because it's a native keyboard and it's in UIWebView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround solution for this problem. If you add type="email" instead of type="text" in your HTML file like bellow, iOS keyboard won't show the predictive view :)

```
<input type="email"/>
```

I temporarily mark this answer as the solution but if someone finds a way to do it from Objective-C part, I'll test and accept that answer as the solution.