# iOS 8 - Remove Previous/Next/Done UIKeyboard Toolbar inside a UIWebView (works iOS 7, not iOS 8)

Tags: ios, uiwebview, ios8, uikeyboard, ios8.1

https://stackoverflow.com/a/22468178/3138300

This method works perfect for iOS 7, but it does not work on iOS 8 - the bar remains.

Does anyone know how I can update the code for iOS 8?

Comment: I found the solution for iOS 8. You can check it here: [ iOS 8 - Remove Previous/Next/Done UIKeyboard Toolbar inside a UIWebView][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25022089/remove-next-previous-buttons-inputaccessoryview-for-custom-keyboard-in-ios8