# On iOS7, bar button item icons vanished in input accessory view

Tags: ios7, accessoryview

Moving my app from iOS6.1 to iOS7, all the button that were visible under iOS6.1 in the toolbar I created for the Input Accessory View of the keyboard are not visible anymore (but still active).

I tried all combinations of [myBar setTranslucent:...] and [myBar setBarStyle:...] but no way to make these buttons visible again. They are defined as:

```
      UIBarButtonItem *myButton =[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(mySelector:)];
```

[image: Under iOS 7.1] <-iOS 7.1
[image: Under iOS 6.1] <-iOS 6.1

Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: It might be useful to include explanatory screenshots from iOS 6 & iOS 7 here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution of my problem.

The method I used to remove the standard input accessory view of the uiwebview was the reason of this problem, it left some view displayed that prevented from seeing the new UIToolbar view. I used [the one described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18837551/remove-keyboard-form-toolbar-on-ios7-leaves-a-blur-behind/19042392#19042392) in Stackoverflow and it works.