# Removing Keyboard Top Bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

All the solutions that are posted on Stackoverflow do not work.

1. [Remove Keyboard Form toolbar on ios7 leaves a blur behind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18837551/remove-keyboard-form-toolbar-on-ios7-leaves-a-blur-behind/19042392#19042392)
2. http://cocoainios.blogspot.in/2014/11/ios8-uiwebview-remove-or-modify.html

The second one remove `Done` button, but does not remove the grey background bar of the keyboard top bar. Is there a way to remove this top bar in iOS7 and iOS8?

[image]

Comment: textView.autocorrectionType     = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;

Comment: How do I get reference to textView from UIWebView?