# How to remove inputAccessoryView of UIWebView in iOS7?

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I wanna to remove white inputAccessoryView of UIWebView when load contenteditable text in iO7.

I can remove it by UIWebBrowserView by the code:

```
-(id)inputAccessoryView{
  return nil;
}
```

### But this way use private-API and not pass validation

I also try something like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13143689/how-to-find-uiwebview-toolbar-to-replace-them-on-ios-6) but not work.

Is there any better way? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19042279/983912). Our app uses this method and is in the store.

I dynamically create a class that is a subclass of UIWebDocumentView that has an implementation of `inputAccessoryView` which returns nil.

Comment: Thanks for share!I read your answer and still don't know how to do.Could you please modify it

Comment: What do you need? I explained in the answer. Ask more specifically, and I will try to help.