# How to remove up and down arrow from the iPad Keyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, keyboard

Image 1 : [image: Full iPad Keyboard]

Below image shows up and down arrow in iPad keyboard.
It occurs when we write in the text field of the web view.
The keyboard occurs with this two arrow keys.

How can I remove it, if anyone suggests??
Image2 : [image: I want to remove this arrows from iPad keyboard]

Thank you.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9054016/7456236) stack overflow answer may help you

Comment: thank you @bali for the help. But it does not remove my up and down arrow key may be. :)